# Inrush current NTC calculation

Tags: thermistor

I have some trouble with choosing an NTC to limit the inrush current, where I want to bypass the NTC with a relay after a certain time.

The choosen NTC should be one of these here:
https://www.mouser.ch/ds/2/18/AAS-920-325D-Thermometrics-NTC-Inrush-031814-web-850596.pdf

There is a total input capacitance of 5mF after the NTC and the Power Supply delivers 24V with a maximum of 30A.

The following schematic depicts the circuit, except that there is no transformer as load, but an input capacitance of 5mF.

[image]

The differntial equation system seems pretty complicated, since there are non-linearities from the ntc, which should be taken into account. Somehow I need to know the resistance over time, such that I can calculate the voltage at the input capacitance over time and so the current through the NTC. Has anyone an idea how to get a differential equation relation of the current and the NTC resistance?

Comment: If you are using a relay then why bother with an NTC. Alternatively, if you are using an NTC, why bother with a relay?

Comment: You may want a time delay on relay

Comment: @Andy Best of both worlds! Although I prefer straight R instead of NTC and bypass with relay.

Comment: Well, the delay for the relay comes from the input capacitance, such that the relay will close at around 15V. A straight R may be a possibility too, but I think normally a thermistor is used for such an application.

Comment: Define your max I desired, E for load (1.725J) and  the R25 is 1.4*120V/IMAX if you do not use ZCS triac to turn on... and E for PTC must be > E load with an R25/R150 ratio >10 or compare input Effective ESR to PTC ESR vs E(t) . What are your unstated V(t), I(t) ESR variables??